# Difference between Seq and Array for array value

Tags: .net, f#

I'm quite new in F#.

I guess arrays are still collections, so I could use `Seq` for iterating the array like this:

```
[|"a"; "b"|] |> Seq.map (fun f -> printfn "a") |> ignore;;
```

But that doesn't work - it prints nothing.
On the other hand if I use `Array`, it prints the strings:

```
[|"a"; "b"|] |> Array.map (fun f -> printfn "a") |> ignore;;
```

Why is that?

Comment: You are not using `printf` function properly here, `printfn "a"` only prints string "a". If you want to print any value you have to use `printfn "%A" anyValue`. See Printf module for all possible formating markers (`%`): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx

Comment: Thx for info. I just came from C#, so I assumed that its something similar as `string.Format` (it doesn't care if you pass some arguments in, so `string.Format("{0}", 'a') works and `string.Format("a")` works too. Simply - I wasn't looking for the right command. Thx :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.map` builds another array - which means it has to do it eagerly. You can't build an array and say "I'll fill in the values when you want them."

Sequences, on the other hand, *are* evaluated lazily... it's only when you ask for the values within the result sequence that the mapping will be evaluated. As stated in the documentation for [`Seq.map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370346.aspx):

> The given function will be applied as elements are demanded using the MoveNext 
>   method on enumerators retrieved from the object.

If you're familiar with LINQ, it's basically the difference between [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) (lazily producing a sequence) and [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) (eagerly projecting an array).

Neither of these are the way to *iterate* over an array or a sequence though - they're *projections*. As Stringer Bell says, `Array.iter` and `Seq.iter` are the appropriate functions for iteration.

Comment: Thx, that comparison to `Enumerable.Select` is perfect.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `Seq.iter` if you want to iterate on your collection, just like that:

```
[|"a"; "b"|] |> Seq.iter (fun f -> printfn "%A" f);;
```

Also you can just use `Array.iter`, if only iterating on arrays:

```
[|"a"; "b"|] |> Array.iter (fun f -> printfn "%A" f);;
```

Another (and shorter) alternative  is directly piping your value into `printfn "%A"` function:

```
[|"a"; "b"|] |> printfn "%A";;
```

will print `[|"a"; "b"|]`. Note that in this case F# prints it exactly like you would have coded it.